# React CSS theming

Tags: css, reactjs

I am just wondering can I define primary color in App.css and then use it in component css files?
For example:
App.css

```
:root {
 --primary-color: blue;
}
```

And then use it in component
Nav.css

```
background-color: --primary-color
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @LV98 Yes, nothing happens, so I was wondering is there any other way or I am doing it wrong

Comment: https://malcoded.com/posts/react-component-style/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the file where you defined the variable is imported in the child or the parent component. I think it would even work if any of the rendered component is using that file but i am not sure about that one.

Comment: You are right, if I want  to use that functionality I need to import at top App.css `@import "../../App.css` in Nav.css